# argument is too long bucle for

Tags: bucle-for, shell, bucles, shell-script

Estoy tratando de concatenar muchisimos archivos de una ruta especifica a traves de un shell script pero como son demasiados genera el error "cat:argumentis to long"
El script es el siguiente:

```
ruta_ori="/salida/sdp_tmp"
ruta_fin="/salida/sdp_tmp/concatenado"
fileName="urbanos"

for i in $(cat "$ruta_fin"/$fileName.txt)
       do
       cd $ruta_ori; cat $i* >> $ruta_fin/$i".txt"
       cd $ruta_ori; rm $i*
       done
```

Les agradezco como puedo mejorar el código :)